# Having a url of : 'example.com' instead of 'localhost:8888/drupal' [Mamp]

Tags: url-rewriting, localhost, mamp

How can i run local tests ( with mamp ) that have urls of this kind : www.example.com instead of http://localhost:8888/install.folder

Thank you

Comment: if the purpose is to simply take screenshots, i would suggest that after you load the page, just type over localhost:8888, and take the screenshot. for any other purpose, use a TLD which does not exist, like .test or .lho, to make it totally foolproof.

Answer (score 2):

If your tests are truely local, you may simply add an alias in your hosts file (/etc/hosts on linux).  This alias will cause your computer to resolve www.example.com as 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

If you wish to use this outside of your computer, you will need to purchase a domain, and set its DNS up to forward to your IP address (and open the appropriate port in your router to forward to your computer).

If you don't want to have to include the port number (':8888'), change the port that your server is being hosted on to the default (80).  This may be done through the server's configuration file by changing the 'Listen' directive.

If you do not want to have to add the '/drupal' path, add an 'Alias' directive to redirect the user from the root path ('/') to '/drupal'.  You may also change the 'DocumentRoot' to drupal.

Comment: It seems, Try adding an additional entry for just groovurb.com (no www).

Comment: Hello, it works but as Andrew Hare said, i still need to add the port number.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but in the future, just mark the answer as accepted so others can find it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an entry to your hosts file like this:

```
127.0.0.1    www.example.com
```

Note: this will not keep you from having to enter the port number or directory - it will only allow you to use a host alias for the host name itself.

Comment: Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file) has good information on hosts file, their syntax, and their location on various platforms. From experience, I'll tell you that a) you really do need to restart your computer if you change it, and b) at least on Windows, if the location you're putting the file is empty, you're in the wrong place.

Comment: I can't get that link to display right. Add a closing ) after the word file.

Comment: the key word here is "add".  you should still keep the localhost line